# Access MySQL json column parameter as NULL if it is unknown

Tags: mysql, json

I have a JSON column type called `data` with the following value:

```
{"name": "tester", "email": "tester@example.com"}
```

I can utilize these values via `data->name` etc.

However, if I try to access an unknown parameter like `data->phone`, I get an `unknown parameter` error because that particular parameter does not exist.

How can I query this so that it will default to `null` if I try to access a parameter that does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for extracting a JSON field is not `data->phone`, it's `data->'$.phone'`.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path

If you use the syntax correctly, it returns NULL when there is no field found matching your search.

Demo on MySQL 8.0.14:

```
create table j (data json);

insert into j set data='{"name": "tester", "email": "tester@example.com"}';

select data->email from j;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'email from j' at line 1

select data->'$.email' from j;
+----------------------+
| data->'$.email'      |
+----------------------+
| "tester@example.com" |
+----------------------+

select data->'$.phone' from j;
+-----------------+
| data->'$.phone' |
+-----------------+
| NULL            |
+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge,the data you have in is stored as object. And -> operator is used to get data from array.
U can use the name of the variable in which you have stored the object to get the data.

Like this -

var d ={
"name": "tester", 
"email": "tester@example.com"
};

// now to access it

d["name"] will give your desired result

Comment: This isn't the problem. The problem is attempting to query unknown parameters.